# Will Google Chrome Frame be Installable on Locked down Windows Machines?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, html5

Does anyone know if [Google Chrome Frame](http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-wave-in-internet-explorer.html) will be installable onWindows machines in the dreaded Corporate IT World where machines are locked down with a Khaki Fist?

I suppose that's really two questions

1. Can Windows be locked down to prevent IE from installing plug-ins?
2. Is Google being clever and finding a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome Frame is a neat idea.

For an answer to your first question, you can absolutely prevent IT from installing plugins. Here is the [GPO area](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx):

- Allow third-party browser extensions: Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Advanced Page
- Add-on List: Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management
- Deny all add-ons unless specifically allowed in the Add-on List: Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management

I don't think Google can get around this, at least in the plugin arena. However, I thought I read somewhere that Chrome's installation program is pretty novel, in that it installs itself in a user's own area and not the system, meaning it installs (on XP) in c:\documents and settings\username... rather than c:\program file.... You might find that you are able to install the normal installer, depending on your GPO settings.

Comment: Adding to Dave's answer, as far as I know there is no such thing as a "per-user" IE plugin. Non-administrators will should not be able to install the plugin (unless Google does some hacking). Your users aren't administrators... right?